# SQL get offline website by threshold

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (actually I have a lot more, but that doesn't matter):

```
sourcewebsite:
id - int (PK)
name - varchar
offlinethreshold - int

sourcewebsite_updatelog:
id - int (PK)
sourcewebsiteid - int (FK)
datetime_start - datetime
episodestotal - int
```

The sourcewebsite tables holds a couple of sourcewebsites, with an offlinethreshold that indicates how many hours the website is allowed to be offline.

The sourcewebsite_updatelog table is a logging table that is filled with a new entry every time a sourcewebsite is checked. If 'episodestotal' equals 0, it means the website was offline when the check occured.

What I want now is this: I want a list of all the websites that exceeded their offlinethreshold. So let's assume we have a sourcewebsite with ID 1, and an offlinethreshold of 6 hours. Let's assume that this website is checked 5 times during the last 6 hours, but every time it was checked, 'episodestotal' was 0. This means that this website exceeded its threshold and can therefore be considered to be offline.

I came up with a little SQL query to determine all sourcewebsites that have been offline for the past 6 hours, but the problem is that these '6 hours' are hardcoded. I want to use the values from the 'offlinethreshold' column for each sourcewebsite.

This is the query that I came up with so far:

```
SELECT `sourcewebsiteid`, `name`
FROM `sourcewebsite_updatelog`
JOIN `sourcewebsite`
ON `sourcewebsite_updatelog`.`sourcewebsiteid` = `sourcewebsite`.`id`
WHERE `datetime_start` > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
GROUP BY `sourcewebsiteid`
HAVING MAX(`episodestotal`) = 0
```

Here's some sample data:

```
sourcewebsite:
1 - channel 1 - 5
2 - channel 2 - 3
3 - channel 3 - 10

sourcewebsite_updatelog:
1 - 1 - 2012-09-27 12:03:05 - 1
2 - 2 - 2012-09-27 12:50:20 - 0
3 - 3 - 2012-09-27 12:51:11 - 1
4 - 1 - 2012-09-27 13:25:56 - 0
5 - 2 - 2012-09-27 13:48:34 - 0
6 - 3 - 2012-09-27 13:59:01 - 0
7 - 1 - 2012-09-27 14:23:53 - 1
8 - 1 - 2012-09-27 14:54:28 - 0
9 - 2 - 2012-09-27 15:11:40 - 0
```

Let's assume that we check the data at 2012-09-27 15:30. Channel 1 has a threshold of 5 hours. It has been online 2 times during the last 5 hours (at 12:03 and 14:23) so it won't be flagged as 'offline'.

Channel 2 has been offline every single time during the last 3 hours, so it must be flagged as offline.

Channel 3 has been online 1 time during the last 10 hours, so it's okay. No flag needed.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may get a better answer if you can provide sample data, and expected output - including data that would make a site offline, as well as data that would show a site to be online.

Comment: Your sample's `datetime_start` does not appear on your pseudo schema. I suspect it is an important column. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ShlomiNoach Ah, datetime_start is the name of the column that indicates when the entry in the sourcewebsite_updatelog was created.

Comment: @AdamWenger I added sample data. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yay, it looks like I finally got the query right. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT `sourcewebsiteid`, `name`
FROM `sourcewebsite_updatelog`
JOIN `sourcewebsite`
ON `sourcewebsite_updatelog`.`sourcewebsiteid` = `sourcewebsite`.`id`
WHERE HOUR(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), `sourcewebsite_updatelog`.`datetime_start`)) < `sourcewebsite`.`offlinethreshold`
GROUP BY `sourcewebsiteid`
HAVING MAX(`episodestotal`) = 0
```

Not too difficult, I just had to use another function for the date subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I completely get you but TimeDiff might be the way to go, something like

```
SELECT `sourcewebsiteid`, `name`
FROM `sourcewebsite_updatelog`
JOIN `sourcewebsite`
ON `sourcewebsite_updatelog`.`sourcewebsiteid` = `sourcewebsite`.`id`
WHERE  (Time_to_sec(TimeDiff(Now(), `datetime_start`)) / 3600) >= `sourcewebsite`.`offlinethreshold`
GROUP BY `sourcewebsiteid`
```

No mysql to test it, and you many need to cast x / 3600 or even round it.

I've no idea what episodes_total is, but try

```
SELECT `sourcewebsiteid`, `name`,
TimeDiff(Now(), `datetime_start`) as difftime,
Time_to_sec(TimeDiff(Now(), `datetime_start`)) as difftimesecs,
(Time_to_sec(TimeDiff(Now(), `datetime_start`)) / 3600) as difftimehours,
`oflinethreshold`,
max(`episodes_total`) as totalepisodes
FROM `sourcewebsite_updatelog`
JOIN `sourcewebsite`
ON `sourcewebsite_updatelog`.`sourcewebsiteid` = `sourcewebsite`.`id`
GROUP BY `sourcewebsiteid`
```

so you can see which bit of my answer isn't doing what I thought.

Comment: I added HAVING MAX(`episodestotal`) = 0 to the bottom because I only want the sourcewebsites that has only 0's in the episodestotal column for the last x hours, but that doesn't return any results. The query in my initial post does (with the same offlinethreshold of 6 hours).

Comment: Beefed it up to show the data it should be filtering against, so you can see if I messed up.

Comment: I rewrote my original question. I hope it's more clear what I'm trying to do now :)